# How to send messages/video recommendations using v3?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

As of a bit earlier this month YouTube messaging api v2 stopped working. I did not find a way to send messages/video recommendations with v3.

How to send messages/video recommendations using v3?

Answer (score 0):

from [their docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages):

> We are reworking YouTube's messaging functionality. While the v2 API
>   has already been deprecated, some API functionality related to
>   messages and video sharing will begin returning errors as early as
>   March 31, 2014.
>
> At that time, the API will return 403 (Forbidden) HTTP responses to
>   requests to send or delete messages. The API will continue to support
>   retrieval of a user's inbox for around six months after that date.
>   After that time, the API will return an empty list in response to a
>   request to retrieve a user's inbox.
>
> **We're excited to provide a new and better API for messaging and video
>   sharing later this year.**

Comment: Yes. That is why I am asking regarding v3.